# Vertical center UL menu and IMG in a #menu div

Tags: css, image, menu, html-lists, vertical-alignment

Sorry for asking stuff that's already been explained a lot but none of the solutions that I saw so far on StackOverflow is actually working for me(table-cell, text-align, vertical-align...nothing).

Here's the deal: all of my code is inside a #box div which is the one dealing with the centering and containing all the elements. The first div after this is #menu and it's like this:

```
<div id="menu">
 <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
 <ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
  <li>menu5</li>
 </ul>          
</div>
```

Nothing special actually, it's pretty simple. My CSS looks like this:

```
#menu {
    background-color: #babadc;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px; }

#menu img {
    float: left; }

#menu ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal; }

#menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

Be ware that I'm using a basic **CSS Reset** to avoid most problems when I'll go test cross-browsing.
The problem here is no matter which of the solutions I try from StackOverflow, only the IMG or the UL vertically centers or they're slightly non-aligned.

**What I'm asking for is:** what's the BEST WAY today to do such a simple task with html/css only(the img size won't change) and have a logo image and a menu on its right perfectly center on the vertical space in a div with known width and height?

I obviously cleaned cache, refreshed, did everything so I'm sure changes are taking effect...I'm just missing something really stupid probably but I really can't center both.

To better show what I want I made this, this should be really a basic menu setup yet something ain't working as expected. Here's my desired outcome, just remember I didn't write any rule to move img and #menu ul from the left/right borders because, obviously, right now they're on the side borders...I'll give margins later.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this is what you want? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/18zetrr6/)

you just need to make the `li` to `inline-block`, add `line-height` to the div `#menu` with the same value as `height`, and add style `vertical-align: middle` to the `img`, here's the full `CSS` needed with the same `HTML` as yours

```
#menu {
    background-color: #babadc;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
}
#menu img {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    /*vertical-align: middle; this is not needed because already declare line-height in parent*/
}
```

note that the `vertical-align: middle` for image work because it's following the other `inline` or `inline-block` element, and the `inline` or `inline-block` element is in the middle because of the `line-height` that's set on the `#menu`. And you also need to make sure that the container `width` is always greater then the total of `image` width and `ul` width for this to work

Comment: This worked. Apparently the image being floated to left prevented it form aligning vertically...why is that? I thought whenever you float two elements on the same line or side by side you always need to float one to left, one to right and then clear.

Comment: @daghene because a `floated` element will be separated from the current flow of the `element` just like position `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: Should have remembered that! I have one last issue with this, on the a:hover state I should display a 2px border on top of the menu. Not on the works but on the top part of the div, is it possible considering I used this trick?

I can give padding and margins but it's not always the same considering I altered the height of the element.

Comment: @daghene, sorry I don't really get what you want. Can you provide some fiddle with the `hyperlink` in it and an image of how you want it? because your current `HTML` didn't have any `hyperlink`. Is it inside each `<li>`, and did you want the border on hover at `<li>`?

Comment: exactly. I know how to do it on a normal menu but considering this has been styled a bit it's somehow not working.

Let's say when you hover on the li/a for that menu there should be a border not just above the text but on the upper part of the menu voice, so basically on the top of the line-height I guess? It keeps showing on the text with this styling somehow.

Basically I'm trying to achieve this: http://imgur.com/dx1fOh7

The big red box is the current page, the top red border is the hover state. This styling kinda gives me problems with this.

Comment: @daghene perhaps this is what you want to have? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/18zetrr6/3/), look at the class `selected` for the `<li>` and the `CSS` for `li:hover:before`

Comment: Yep that's exactly the case! Thank you Kyojimaru, you really saved my day :) now I see what I was missing, some basic stuff but after hours of code I still get lost somehow eheh.

Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can work from this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgbztyhn/2/)

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.thenextbestweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/shell.jpg" alt="logo"   height="80%" width="auto">
```

CSS

```
body {
outline: 0;
margin:0;
}

#menu {
background-color: #babadc;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}


#menu img {
float: left;
top: 10%;
position: absolute;
}

#menu ul {
float: right;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal; 
background-color: #FF0000;
height: 20px;
margin-top: 40px;}

#menu li {
display: table-cell;
padding-left: 20px;
 }
```

Just look at the fiddle....

Comment: Agreed on the fact there's cleaner options but it's a good alternative, tried it too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the height is known and fixed, I would suggest

- ensure that there is no top/bottom padding/margins on `ul`, `li` and `a`. Set `line-height` to 1 on `a`
- manually set top margins for `img` and `ul` based on the height of nav and height of images. `ul` height will be your `font-size` once all extra padding is removed. (margin-top = nav height minus half of image/ul height)

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/no5wo77a/1/

Comment: There's a more light version on the code side by Kyojimaru but this worked too, thank you for the alternative!